# Azure Mobile Services Custom API Getting Bad Request on Client

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-mobile-services

So I'm using azure mobile services backend to try and make a custom API. However I can't seem to connect to even the template table from the client. When you make a new Azure Mobile Service using the template they provide you with this `values` API controller that resembles this format

```
[MobileAppController]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    [Route("api/values")]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

From the client I'm trying to invoke this endpoint like this

```
var result = mobileService.InvokeApiAsync<string>("values", HttpMethod.Get, null).Result;
```

And for some reason I keep getting this exception

`{"The request could not be completed.  (Bad Request)"}`

`{Method: GET, RequestUri: 'http://localhost:58457/api/values', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
  X-ZUMO-FEATURES: AT
  X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: b04f4e19-4f41-46ed-9767-9c1352037559
  Accept: application/json
  User-Agent: ZUMO/1.3
  User-Agent: (lang=Managed; os=Windows; os_version=6.1.65536.7601; arch=Win32NT; version=1.3.30324.0)
  X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/1.3 (lang=Managed; os=Windows; os_version=6.1.65536.7601; arch=Win32NT; version=1.3.30324.0)
}}`

This is only the template too, so I need this to work before I get any of my custom endpoints up and running. Any ideas on what the issue may be?

Comment: Can you make the same request via fiddler or postman? Do you still get a 400 response? Looks like you're trying to hit localhost:58457... that's correct, right?

Comment: Using an HTTP client I'll get an error about missing the Zumo header in the request. The new mobile services seem to require that now

Comment: @DillonDrobena did my answer below work for you as well ?

Comment: @RamiSarieddine Unfortunately I did not get to try your solution as the problem I was having was directly related to the answer I chose. I simply was using the wrong package. As soon as I upgraded it things worked perfectly. If this was related to the version check, I cannot be sure unless I downgrade the package again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say Mobile Service, but the controller you're using is MobileAppController.

This indicates you're actually using Mobile App.  If you look in your server project packages.config, you may see something like this.

```
 <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server" version="1.0.119.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

I suspect that the 400 you are getting is because you're using a Mobile Client version less than 2.0.0.

In your client project package config, try using a newer client version, such as:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="win81" />
```

You should also inspect the body of the 400 response to get an explicit error message.  I expect it to say something like:

```
{"message":"No API version was specified in the request, this request needs to specify a ZUMO-API-VERSION of '2.0.0'.  For more information and supported clients see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690568#2.0.0"}
```

Comment: This was the problem actually. With azure rolling out their new app services a lot of the nuget packages are getting a bit confusing. There's still WindowsAzure.MobileServices floating around a long with Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client. The migration from mobile services to app services is still fuddling with my API it seems

Answer (score 12):

You can opt out of version checking by setting a value of true for the app setting MS_SkipVersionCheck. Specify this either in your web.config or in the Application Settings section of the Azure Portal. 
[image]ms_skipversioncheck to true in the portal.

Comment: Thanks @freethinker6

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-client-and-server-versioning

which actually says both Mobile Apps client and server SDKs are originally based on those in Mobile Services, but they are not compatible with each other. That is, you must use a Mobile Apps client SDK with a Mobile Apps server SDK and similarly for Mobile Services. This contract is enforced through a special header value used by the client and server SDKs, ZUMO-API-VERSION.

So, you must add Headers in the request

HEADERS: ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0

Or

http://localhost/api/values/get?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0

Or

You can opt out of version checking by setting a value of true for the app setting MS_SkipVersionCheck, specify this in your web.config under

Answer (score 0):

Actually even if you specify what version of client you are using in your package.config you will still get the same error of Bad Request. No Zumo version specified.  You must pass into your InvokeApiAsync method a parameter specifying the version. For example:

```
var arguments = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"ZUMO-API-VERSION", "2.0.0" }
            };
var result = MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<string>("CONTROLLERSNAME",  "HttpMethod.Get", arguements).Result;
```

and bingo it will work.