# Error thrown while performing ajax call to web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following basic code. I tried to debug this code but the javascript is very painful to debug, and I do not know where it is failing:

```
 jQuery.support.cors = true;
            var packet = {
                Image: imageAsString,
                PhnType: phoneType,
                PhnMdl: phoneManufacturer
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://molecheckerservices2.azurewebsites.net/api/Testing/SubmitTestingData",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ packet }),
                success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    alert('yes');
                    window.localStorage.setItem("dataObject", JSON.stringify(data));
                    window.location = "results.html";
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('no');
                    window.localStorage.setItem("dataObject", JSON.stringify([.33, .33, .33]));
                    window.location = "results.html";
                }
```

it gives me back an alert no, which corresponds with a failure. Additionally as I debug I see in my Javascript console that the error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Pops up. I tried to look up what this mean but I would be incredibly grateful for any problem specific advice!

Comment: Have you tried posting without using JSON.stringify?

Comment: yes i have tried that I first thought that it was badly formatted data pasing through causing the error

Comment: Have you considered adding this contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", to your ajax settings?

Comment: no I did not will try now!

Comment: Read the error. "the **server** responded with a status of 400".  You should check what your server is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up Fiddler and manually `POST` to your endpoint. If you do that, you will see the same error message I saw:
`{"message":"No API version was specified in the request, this request needs to specify a ZUMO-API-VERSION of '2.0.0'.  For more information and supported clients see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690568#2.0.0"}`

It has a handy-dandy link in there for you. Also, [here is a SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382200/azure-mobile-services-custom-api-getting-bad-request-on-client) that possibly applies to you.

I did add the header mentioned above, resent the request and I received that sweet `200` response from your service, so I'm pretty sure that's your issue.

P.S. If you don't want random strangers inserting data into your app like I just did, you should secure your service or at least obfuscate the URL when mentioning it in public.